# Visualising intersections in sets using UpSet for R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am currently using the [UpSet](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/UpSetR) package in RStudio to visualise the intersections in 6 datasets containing approx 400 variables. I have plotted a histogram where I can see the number of intersecting variables within each set.

However I would like to know what these variables are that participate in each intersection. Which command can I use to get UpSet to tell me this information?

Comment: So you want to see, which variables are the same between 1st and 2nd dataset, 1st and 3rd, 2nd and 3rd etc ?

Comment: Yes; I would like to see which variables are the same between all datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```
dt1 <- data.table(v1=c(rep(1,10)),
                  v2=c(rep(1,10)),
                  v3=c(rep(1,10)))

dt2 <- data.table(v1=c(rep(1,10)),
                  v2=c(rep(1,10)),
                  v4=c(rep(1,10)))

dt3 <- data.table(v5=c(rep(1,10)),
                  v2=c(rep(1,10)),
                  v4=c(rep(1,10)))
dt <- list(dt1,dt2,dt3)

Reduce(intersect, lapply(dt,function(x){names(x)}))

# [1] "v2"
```